# How to show console output in Typescript playground

Tags: typescript

I can refresh TypeScript playground and it loads with the previous code I already had written but none of the buttons work. I can't open the sidebar. Pressing run doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should change your title to fit to the problem described. The answer to your question in the title would be: "hit the run button. Console logs will be displayed on the right hand side."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing browsing data including cookies did the trick for me.

In Chrome, I did the following:

1. Open Settings
2. Select History
3. Select clear browsing data
4. Select options desired - "last hour" worked for me